# Specify \svgscale instead of \svgwidth for Inkscape pdf_tex

Tags: graphics, scaling, svg, inkscape

The `image.pdf_tex` documents created with Inkscape's PDF+LaTeX export use this code

```
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{293.02998953bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
```

which makes it sound that instead of the usual

```
\def\svgwidth{15cm}
\input{image.pdf_tex}
```

you could do something like

```
\def\svgscale{0.2}
\input{image.pdf_tex}
```

However, it gives an error in pdflatex's output:

```
(.image.pdf_tex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \unitlength * \real 
                               {\svgscale }
l.43 ...nitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}
                                                  %
?
```

How can I make this work?

The reason is that I want to include to vector graphic subfigures that have different sizes, but at should be displayed at the same scale.

Comment: the package is using `calc` package syntax so add `\usepackage{calc}` to your document.

Comment: Note that changing that one line to `\setlength{\unitlength}{\svgscale\unitlength}%` seems to work, but since this is an autogenerated document it doesn't feel like the right way?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yup, that does the trick! If you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package is using `calc` package syntax so add

```
\usepackage{calc}
```

to your document.